# Allow HTML in text boxes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

How can I allow users to enter HTML into a textbox?
I'm seting `validaterequest` to `false` and still getting this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Summary="`<a>`").

I know its not recommended etc, but it's for internal use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the `ValidateInput(false)` attribute to your action

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult MyAction (int id, string content) {
}
```

Answer (score 28):

If you are using DataAnnotations on your model, you can open up a single property to allow HTML by using the [`AllowHtml` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute). Note that this attribute is in the System.Web.Mvc namespace.

This would probably be recommended over setting ValidateInput to false at the action level.

Comment: Agree with @jlnorsworthy.  Use the AllowHtml attribute.

Comment: @jlnorsworthy right but allowhtml not accept <a> tag. What can i do?

Comment: [AllowHtml] still open a hole for script injection and XSS. I developed a custom annotation to remove scripts and any unwanted HTML tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44140165/538387