# How do I allow selective HTML input in my ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'd like the end-user to type in text without any formatting in a text area in my ASP.NET MVC application. However, I would like to retain any line breaks or paragraphs that they have created when typing in their text.

If I use a textarea without allowing HTML input, by default, the line breaks and paragraphs are not retained when this text is saved to the database or read back to be displayed on the user interface.

If I `AllowHTML`, I run the risk of code injection.

The only other way I can think of implementing this is to *not* `AllowHTML` but instead have a custom attribute that checks allows only for `<p>` tags and `<br />` tags, but then for implementing that, simple as it might seem, I will have to maintain a dictionary of all possible HTML tags and, with the nature of the Web being so volatile, god knows what other syntactical tokens from CSS or something.

Am I over-complicating the issue? Is there something out of the box or is there an easier way to implement this?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 targeting ASP.NET 4.5.

Comment: What do you mean _retain any line breaks_? If the user is just typing plain text and uses the return key to enter a new paragraph, then it will be retained.

Comment: But line breaks are retained so not sure why your claiming they are not. If you mean in a display view (e.g. `<div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>`) you don't see them, its because you need to style the element with `whitespace:pre;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you. That's the right answer. :-)

Comment: And do it using css, not by replacing the newline characters (which is `\n\r`, not `\n`) with a `<br/>` tag :)

Comment: I have just answered it here with a more flexible approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44140165/538387

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textarea` keeps line breaks as `\n` characters. When displaying the value afterwards outside textarea element as part of the page the `'\n'` characters need to be replaced with `'<br />'`.

Comment: For anyone else like me reading this, as @StephenMuecke suggested in the comment to my question, instead of doing the replace operation manually, simply style the element that displays the text with `white-space: pre`.